# GXT Grid Layout issue - No Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: extjs, grid, scrollbar, gxt

I'm trying to add a Grid into a VerticalLayoutContainer of fixed size (250 px) and have the user be able to scroll vertically.

I'm using the following code, however, the grid does not display at all.

```
    VerticalLayoutContainer vPanel = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
    vPanel.setHeight("250px");
    vPanel.add(grid, new VerticalLayoutData(1, 1));

    grid.setHeight("auto");

    add(vPanel);
```

The Grid displays in other circumstances, but covers up other GUI elements (no scrollbar).

Hopefully this is an easy fix for those more experienced with Sencha GXT.

Thanks to anyone taking the time to help me out...

Comment: What type of component are you adding the vPanel to (i.e. the add(vPanel) method)? A ContentPanel?

Comment: It's a Flow Layout Container...

Comment: Ok few more questions - 1. What version of GXT are you using? 2. Does the code example provided not work at all (i.e. no grid displayed) or does it display but covers other GUI elements?  3. Are there other elements on the page you are also trying to render?

Comment: He has to be using GXT 3 since its a VerticalLayoutContainer

Comment: If you are adding the VLC to a FLC, I believe that the VLC needs to have all of its sizes set explicitly. Have you tried setting the width as well?

Comment: @Bionic_Geek: 1. I'm using GXT 3 and 2. The grid does not display at all. If I simply add it (no Vpanel, just adding it to the FLC then it will cover other GUI elements). 3. There are a ton of other elements, but this is in its own "module" so to speak, separate from the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`vPanel.getScrollSupport().setScrollMode(ScrollMode.auto);`

If it doesn't work, then, try this:

`

```
ContentPanel p = new ContentPanel();
p.setHeaderVisable(false);
p.setBodyBorder(false);
p.setBorder(false);
p.setHeigh(250);
vPanel.add(p);
p.add(grid);
```

`

then grid, will automaticaly have scroll mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a `Grid` in a `ContentPanel`, that is, the grid didn't show a vertical scrollbar. I used `ContentPanel#forceLayout` immediately after adding the grid to the panel, and it resolved the problem. Here's the actual code:

```
Grid<Pet> grid = new Grid<>(listStore, columnModel);
grid.setBorders(true);
grid.setColumnReordering(true);
grid.setLoadMask(true);
grid.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
grid.setView(createGridView());
ContentPanel contentPanel = new ContentPanel();
contentPanel.setHeaderVisible(false);
contentPanel.add(grid);
contentPanel.forceLayout(); // <---- this is the line that fixed the problem!
```